# Laravel 5.1 package to Log all events installation: missing log file and nothing written

Tags: windows, logging, installation, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to use a [laravel-request-logger](https://github.com/andersao/laravel-request-logger).

1. I followed the installation steps and set the log level to debug.
2. Then changed the log level to debug
3. Ran `composer update` and composer `dump-autoload`
4. Tried several good and bad requests

First I didn't even find the file mentioned *http.log* anywhere in my app folder, neither in my storage folder (where the only **logs** folder is).
So I created the **http.log** file myself within the `storage\logs` folder and gave all users write permissions. But nothing is written after several good and bad requests.

Second, I notice the default `laravel.log` hasn't logged anything since installing this package, probably because this package overules the default?

Comment: Did you made the storage folder and his subfolders writable? By default Laravel  logs in this folder. As you say it is possible that the package overules the default. I am using the default log system ad I don't have any problem with it.

Comment: I assume it was working fine until I added this package, because I see log errors in the `laravel.log` up till the moment I installed this

Comment: You don't really need this package cause you can anytime look at your logs in the storage :)

Comment: @Franco is there a way to specify different logs for different controller and or methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Laravel’s logging features are managed by Monolog53, you have a wide array of additional logging options at your disposal, including the ability to write log messages to this log file, set logging levels, send log output to the Firebug console54 via FirePHP55, to the Chrome console56 using Chrome Logger57, or even trigger alerts via e-mail, HipChat58 or Slack59.

```
public function index(){
     $items = [
          'one',
          'two'
      ];

      \Log::debug($items);

      return view('about');
}
```

Aa customized log message similar to the following will
be appended to storage/logs/laravel.log:

```
[2015-12-14 01:51:56] local.DEBUG: 
    array ( 0 => 'Pack luggage',
    'one',
    'two'
)
```

There is of course more but it will be to difficult to explain it in here. :) Cheers

Comment: You have a typo on line 6-> debub should be debug.

Comment: @davejal Thanks for point me to this, I was writing directly in here so I didn't notice this. Cheers :)